# alert() and console.log() not working in Firefox 26

Tags: javascript, firefox, alert, console.log

I feel like I'm going crazy but `alert()` and `console.log()` refuses to work **anywhere** on **Firefox 26**.

At first I thought it was my own website's problem, but I cannot for the life of me to get it to work via `javascript:` urls, `Firebug`, I even tried it in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) by just putting `alert('test');` in the script panel.

*Tried uninstalling and installing again, no luck*.

The only extension I'm running is Firebug.

Heck, *Stackoverflow didn't even prompt me about leaving when I accidentally clicked the back button while writing this*.

Also yes, **I made sure there was some content** inside the `alert()` and `console.log()`

What I mean by not working is that Firefox treats the code as if it were non-existent, nothing happens.

---

Once again, here's my environment:
**Browser:** Firefox 26.0 
**OS:** Windows 8.1 Pro 
**Issue:** `alert()`, `console.log()`, and apparently `prompt()` doesn't work

If anyone might know why this is happening, I would highly appreciate an answer.

---

**UPDATE**

Following Pointy's comment, it appears that both `alert()` and `console.log()` work as expected on the **New Tab Page**, but nowhere else

Comment: I have to ask: is JavaScript enabled?

Comment: I had a similar issue, in my case it was one of the addons,

Comment: @pdoherty926 yes I'm 99.99% sure JavaScript is enabled. All other javascript works as expected (e.g. Google Instant Search)

Comment: It may be your firefox version and firbug version is not suitable each

Comment: @JayBhatt suresh.g following FroggyDay's answer, I uninstalled firebug too and now I have absolutely 0 extensions, still not working though

Comment: So if you open a new tab, bring up the developer console, and type "alert('hello world')", nothing happens?

Comment: @Pointy wait actually it does. **Only** on the `New Tab Page`. Nowhere else.

Comment: @KevinPei so, like, here on the Stackoverflow page, it also doesn't work?

Comment: @Pointy nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for bad question but i have to ask how you are checking alert?That may be cause problem

Comment: @dholakiyaankit anyway I can. Via the console, jsfiddle, and my own test webpage. For example, http://jsfiddle.net/b38p6/1/ doesn't alert anything for me.

Comment: Buddy it works for me here

Comment: Do you have addons enabled like noscript etc ??

Comment: @dholakiyaankit like I said above, I have absolutely no addons or extensions enabled at this moment

Comment: what and how are you trying to console, could you please show me your relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, in the end I used *Revo Uninstaller* to completely and absolutely wipe Firefox from my system, then installed it again. Seems to be working now, the original uninstaller most likely didn't remove whatever was causing the problem.

Comment: I've had the same issue with firefox 27.0 on mac.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try re-installing Firebug:

- [console.log in firefox is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633404/console-log-in-firefox-is-not-working)

PS:
I happen to be running a similar configuration (including FF 26) ... and things work fine for me.  IMHO...

PPS:
You might also try setting "about:config, prompts.tab_modal.enabled = false":

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=613752

The default is "true", my FF 26 is set "true" and things are working for me ... but who knows.  If reinstalling Firebug doesn't help, maybe it's worth a shot?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly it seems that Firebug is not the problem. I completely uninstalled it and restarted firefox and it's still not working

Comment: @FroggyDay thanks I also tried setting it to false, still not working

Comment: One additional suggestion: see if you can reproduce the problem with a small, self-contained example.  Include the complete HTML, not just the Javascript snippet.  Who knows: maybe there's an issue with *where* you're calling the alert; or something occurring before the alert gets invoked?

Answer (score 3):

Silly but, in firebug can you check if window.alert and window.console are defined.... and if yes then, can you check if  window.alert('hi') works ?

Answer (score 0):

I have same bug when i using Ghostery extension. Disable Ghostery and reload page. Lets check at https://getfirebug.com/tests/head/console/api/log.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, on IE v11.0.10 and Chrome Canary v38.0.2114. Duplicate function name turnout to be the issue. Worth doing a quick check for function names in Javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firefox console with CTRL + SHIFT + K

Related: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/876916