# Console.log does not work inside Self Executing Anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

```
(function() {
    console.log('Hello World');
})();
```

Does not print anything to console.

```
(function() {
    alert('Hello World');
})();
```

Gives an alert. Why so ?

Comment: It works fine for me. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What environment are you trying this in?

Comment: If I just paste this into the Firefox Console, it also does not log anything.

Comment: Works as expected for me in Firefox.

Comment: You know you have to have the dev tools turned on, right?

Comment: It works with `console.info` for me, but not `console.log` (regardless of putting it into a function or not). On FF.

Comment: @Thilo See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29442885/5743988) fixes it.

Comment: I was trying in chrome

Answer (score 2):

Both alert and console are working, please check when you are using console.log in self executing function, you are calling that function by using these brackets () or not. May be you are missing these in your code  -

```
**Incorrect Code -** 
(function() {
    console.log('Hello World');
});
**Correct Code -** 
(function() {
console.log('Hello World');
})();
```

[Correct code](https://jsfiddle.net/b8yu2ft1/)

[image]

Comment: I don't see the correct code working. Can you create a code  snippet and show.

Comment: But i don't see the result of console.log. Did you see ? Here is the screenshot http://prntscr.com/nd3dk1

Comment: image added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't see console logs at all. If using some sort of browser's dev tools you should select the displayed log levels.

I'm using Chrome's dev tools and your code works as expected with info log level enabled.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is99N.png)